# How to bring current line & cursor at 25% from top of screen?

Tags: scrolling

`zz` moves current line & cursor at the middle of the screen.
`zt` moves current line & cursor at the top of the screen.

Is there a way to do the same as `zz` and `zt`, but for a quarter (25%) from the screen top?

---

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
map <silent> <expr> zT "zt" . (&scroll / 2) . "\<c-y>"
```

But it does not do exactly what I want, because if there are wrapped lines that take for example 10 visual lines, one stroke of `<c-y>` will go over those 10 visual lines in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `zz` and `zt` have an special treatment that avoid the visual lines you mentioned in your solution. But if they do have you could try resizing the window:

```
nnoremap <expr> zT 'zzz'.(&scroll).'<CR>Hz'.(&scroll*2).'<CR><C-O>'
```

Notice that this expects that [`'scrolloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scrolloff%27) is set to 0. If you use a different value you could write a function to save the original value and restore it at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Works well for me since I don't use scrolloff.